# Amazon S3 Upload hangs on 100%

Tags: java, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I'm using Amazon's provided [High-Level API](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HLuploadFileJava.html) to upload files to Amazon S3. I use a lightly-modified version of the example provided:

```
public Upload uploadFile() {

    transferManager = new TransferManager(new BasicAWSCredentials("KEY", "SECRETKEY"));
    upload = transferManager.upload(existingBucketName, keyName, new File(filePath));
    return upload;
}
```

Meanwhile, from another thread, I'm measuring its progress:

```
while (!upload.isDone()) {
        System.out.println("upload prog " + upload.getProgress().getPercentTransfered() + " state " + upload.getState());
        Thread.sleep(200);
}
```

The progress reporting itself seems to be working well, as I'm getting progress that makes sense. However, once it reaches 100%, the upload stalls. It looks a lot like the call to isDone() is blocking, as it simply will not update.

### OUTPUT

```
upload prog 91.9009559586608 state InProgress
upload prog 95.31523296022095 state InProgress
upload prog 99.01403304524446 state InProgress
upload prog 100.0 state InProgress
upload prog 100.0 state InProgress
```

The percentage, once it gets to 100%, will not update again. It appears to update twice and then hang.

If I check for the existence of the file externally, using Cyberduck, it appears to have uploaded the file successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your code snippet, you don't get any more updates because you have fallen through your loop, since `upload.isDone()` is true.  If you add:

```
System.out.println("upload prog " + upload.getProgress().getPercentTransfered() + " state " + upload.getState());
```

after the end of your loop, you will see the `Completed` message.  You probably see multiple 100% messages, because the TransferManager is waiting for the upload to complete.